# Laravel file cannot be deleted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to delete a file (a temporary file that I create if my import command fails), which is located under `storage/framework/cache/`.
I tried to use `unlink` but always I get an error `Text file busy` (as I searched, this error is displayed because the file is in use).
I tried also `File::delete($fullpath)` but doesn't work too (no error, but the file is not removed)
The problem is if I check if the file exists, it is always true (I checked also manually and the file is there).
Here what I made:

```
$lockfilePath = $this->lockFilePath($uri);// if i display this line, I get /var/www/html/project/storage/framework/cache/filename.lock
if (!file_exists($lockfilePath)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("$uri was not locked. Lockfile not found.");
}
\File::delete($lockfilePath); // I tried also unlink($lockfilePath);
```

I am working with homestead and Laravel 5.1 (PHP version 5.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve it is to use `unlink($filepath)`, but before that, you need to search where the file was opened and to use `fclose($handle)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

use "File" class before your class begins e.g  `use File;`

```
$lockfilePath = $this->lockFilePath($uri);

if (File::exists($lockfilePath)) {
    unlink($lockfilePath);                      
} else {
    return "file not present";
}
```

**Note:** make sure that your project has **read write permissions** on the files which you want to delete run the below code to provide the permission to read write.

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www
```

( The -R makes it recursive)

Comment: Never. make. it . chmod 777.

Comment: reason ? @abr please

Comment: If you know what chmod stands for @Prashant Prajapati, surely you know that the last digit (7) stands for a full crud permission to anyone.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777  I find this a good explanation, take a look

Comment: which permission should be used to read/write/delete file ? help please

Answer (score 0):

after some search, i found this

Suppose that your file is under this path **storage/app/public/images**

**Controller**

```
.... other logic code
if( Storage::disk('local')->exists('public/images/'.$file->file_system_path))
            Storage::disk('local')->delete('public/images/'.$file->file_system_path);
```

both the method return a boolean values.

**Important note !**

```
php artisan storage:link
```

**/config/filesystem.php**

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you generate the file?

Do you close the file after you create it?

```
fclose($file)
```

---

You can also try to force garbage collection after closing the file and before unlinking it:

```
gc_collect_cycles();
```

Comment: So do you unlock the file before you close it?  flock($fp, LOCK_UN);  // release the lock.. You could provide a little bit more code.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you  close the file and you are not using it .
Also try  `Storage::delete($filepath)` and make sure you have the rights to delete the file since it's inside *laravel storage*

Comment: `Storage::delete($filepath)` will automatically search in the path `storage/app/` then it will never find the file.

Comment: You can define different disks with different paths to use with Storage in config/filesystems.php .